# Magento 2.2.5 Tax is not working

Tags: magento2, tax-calculation

Magento 2.2.5 version tax is not calculating, It always show 0(zero) in cart page and checkout page.

I have been lot of search but not luck, please anyone help to fix this issue.

or

How i can alter tax amount?

Note: Tax class already assigned to product, Tax rule already in admin so please except any other solution.

[image]

Comment: is it simple product?

Comment: Have you assign class to customer group ?

Comment: yes, Retail Customer class added

Comment: Please check https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-settings-general.html whether you miss anything or not